# Question on inductors with initial current

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, current-source, passive-networks

Question:
Initially the switch position is aa', 3 H is connected across a 3 A supply and 6 H is connected across 6 A supply. After some time the make before break switch is actuated to the new position bb'. Determine the steady state current, fluxes associated with each inductor in the new position. Assume there are no switching losses.
Fig 1 : Initial condition (switch in aa')
Fig 2: circuit while operating the make before break switch 
Fig 3 : switch in bb'

Pre switching period is fine, each inductor having a current of 3 A and 6 A respectively. Inductors don't allow a sudden change in current when disconnected from supply as in fig 3, their magnetic field collapses and allow a decreasing current to flow in the same direction as previous and their  voltages are reversed. But how does it behave when two inductors having different initial currents are switched together? It shouldn't be 9 A otherwise total energy associated with the series inductors is more than pre switching violating law of conservation of energy. Is this case similar to connecting two current sources in series which is not allowed?

[image: circuit]

Comment: What are your thoughts? In a series circuit you can't have different currents in each component and you can't change the current in an inductor in zero time.

Comment: When two inductors \$L_1\$ and \$L_2\$ , with initial currents \$I_{0_1}\$ and \$I_{0_2}\$, come in series, the equivalent inductance becomes \$L_{eq}\$=\$L_1\$+\$L_2\$, and the equivalent initial current \$I_{t_0}=\frac{L_1I_{0_1}+L_2I_{0_2}}{L_1+L_2}\$, derived from \$\phi=LI\$. The voltage of each inductor can change whatever it needs to be to make the current almost suddenly change.

Comment: Huh? What are those weird things labeled a, b, a', and b'?

Comment: @WarrenHill I think it should be 3A, the lower limit set on the system would be the result when the two inductors are fighting. But then again I don't know how to explain where the 81 J went (121.5 J - 40.5 J)

Comment: @dirac16 That sounds like a neat answer. Flux is conserved but how to explain the mismatch in sum of the energies stored in inductors before switching and after switching

Comment: @OlinLathrop  It's a make before break switch. Pardon if the representation is confusing

Comment: *Make before break* refers to SPDT, but are these are DPST that just arc when opened?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist It's similar to the one shown here and they are assumed to be ideal so no arcing. https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F464%2F46463c51-461d-4751-b167-4abf159f997f%2FphpTru5O6.png

Comment: C'mon guys, they are clearly make before break switches however, the hand drawn fig 2 is misleading because it doesn't represent the final circuit.

Comment: An arc will always occur even in an ideal vacuum. Two opposite currents switched with 0V steady state will be like shorting 2 ideal caps charged to some opposite voltage but different energy stored .

Comment: The current sources will go to infinite voltage and arc.